# Can I show data on the new ambient display in android 8.0 and up?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I was wondering if it is possible for third party applications to show data on the android Ambient Display. It is fairly new (android 8.0 and up) so I wasn't able to find any information on it. I have an application in which that would be very useful if I could. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Setting an icon and app name is what you can do for now.

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d18ed49f9dba09b85782c83999a9103dec015bf2/core/java/android/app/Notification.java#L4171

```
bindSmallIcon(contentView, ambient);
bindHeaderAppName(contentView, ambient);
if (!ambient) {
    // Ambient view does not have these
    bindHeaderText(contentView);
    bindHeaderChronometerAndTime(contentView);
    bindProfileBadge(contentView);
}
bindExpandButton(contentView);
```